# How can I stop the "from" view from becoming black when presenting another view controller?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, transition, ios7

I have two view controllers, call them "ViewControllerA" and "ViewControllerB". When the app loads, ViewControllerA is displayed. In ViewControllerA's `touchesEnded:withEvent:`, it calls `presentViewController:` on ViewControllerB. The loading of ViewControllerB works fine; the only problem is that when they're transitioning, ViewControllerA turns black. How can I make ViewControllerA continue to view its contents even while transitioning to ViewControllerB? If it's relevant, I use a custom transition, demonstrated here:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.7f];
[UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
[UIView setAnimationRepeatCount:1.0f];
[UIView setAnimationRepeatAutoreverses:NO];
[UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];

toViewController.view.frame = self.view.bounds;
[self presentViewController:toViewController animated:NO completion:nil];

[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Comment: What is this animation supposed to do? What are the bounds of the toViewController.view to start with?

Comment: @rdelmar - Initially, the bounds cover a small tile on a map, an example being one of the red dots on screen [in this image](http://i.stack.imgur.com/FETGO.png), and when that tile is tapped, the bounds expand to fill the screen. It's aimed to give the user the sense of zooming into the red dot (which represents a city). The animation works fine though; it's just that when the animation starts, the view I'm transitioning from turns black.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you should use the newer block based methods which have been recommended since iOS 4. If you use the one that has a completion block, you can do the presentViewController:animated there (when you present a view controller with animation NO, it will remove the old controller's view immediately, so that's your problem). Here's an example that expands a view from small to full size:

```
-(IBAction)doStuff:(id)sender {
    self.toViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ToVC"];
    self.toViewController.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(.01, .01);
    [self.view.window addSubview:self.toViewController.view];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:2.0 animations:^{
        self.toViewController.view.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        [self presentViewController:self.toViewController animated:NO completion:nil];
    }];
}
```

Comment: Forgot about the updated block syntax version, so thanks for that. But animating the transition this way for some reason causes there to be no animation; the view controller is presented immediately, with no growing animation to accompany it.

Comment: @qegal, It works fine for me, so I don't know what you're doing differently.

Comment: Nevermind, I forgot to add the `addSubview:` line. Thanks a lot!